# how to display data from database according its category example given below

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**database**

```
id project_id tech_section_id tech_category_id technology_used
1     13         1                 3              HTML
2     13         1                 4              css
3     13         2                 7              PHP
4     13         3                 8              java
5     13         3                 10             node.js 
6     13         4                 12             MySQL
```

table output

```
frontend.      backend.        database
 HTML            
 css   
                 PHP            
                 java          
                node.js            
                                 MySQL
```

how to display output like this table

```
frontend.      backend.        database
HTML.            PHP             mysql
css.            java.
               node.js
```

Code which I used

```
@foreach($product_data['stack_used'] as $pro_tech)            
    <tr>
      <td scope="row">@if($pro_tech['tech_section_id']==1) {{$pro_tech['technology_used']}} @endif</td>
      <td>@if($pro_tech['tech_section_id']==2) {{$pro_tech['technology_used']}} @endif</td>
      <td>@if($pro_tech['tech_section_id']==3) {{$pro_tech['technology_used']}} @endif</td>
      <td></td> 
    </tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

controller

```
public function portfolio_detail($id){
      $product_data = project_detail::with('stack_used')->find($id)->toArray();
return view('front hash.index_portfolio_detail')->with(compact('product_data'));
    }
```

how to display data on table from database according its section_id

Answer (score 0):

in each iteration in your view table it create empty `<td>` tags and because of that there is such un ordered list, to solve this problem firstly iterate through your array and concatenate the relevant values with each other and at the end print them:

```
<?php
    $front_end = "";
    $back_end = "";
    $database = "";
?>
@foreach($product_data['stack_used'] as $pro_tech)
    @if($pro_tech['tech_section_id'] == 1)
    <?php $front_end .= $pro_tech['technology_used'] . " <br/>"; ?>
    @elseif($pro_tech['tech_section_id'] == 2)
    <?php $back_end .= $pro_tech['technology_used'] . " <br/>"; ?>
    @elseif($pro_tech['tech_section_id'] == 3)
    <?php $database .= $pro_tech['technology_used'] . " <br/>"; ?>
    @endif
@endforeach
<tr scope="row">
    <td>{!! $front_end !!}</td>
    <td>{!! $back_end !!}</td>
    <td>{!! $database !!}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: it works thank so much what is the difference between {{}} and {!! !!}

Comment: @vishal That one helps to set html elements, I mean if you've some data with some html code and wanna retrieve it as html syntax, you must use {!! !!} instead of {{ }}

Comment: By default, Blade {{ }} statements are automatically sent through PHP's `htmlspecialchars` function to prevent XSS attacks. If you do not want your data to be escaped, you may use the following syntax:{!! $fornt_end !!}, it will render your html tags like <br/> make a break line.